# Where to get started on Receiving and then forwarding an SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

So my idea is to recieve an sms which I've tried to do using the broadcast receiver, process the sms and add something to it and then send that sms back to.a specified address.

Right now, I'm not really sure where to get started. I've tried using a broadcast receiver to retrieve the sms, but I'm not sure how to send the sms back and where to do any processing.

Comment: Do your "processing" in the `BroadcastReceiver` unless it's very CPU intensive; send the response using `SmsManager`. The most complex bit of this is probably the receiver, and you have solved that. Any further responses will invariably write the entire code for you. Include what you have so far to solicit responses.

Comment: Do I need to even have an activity or is the activity needed to register the broadcast receiver?

Comment: No you dont, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083158/send-sms-until-it-is-successful/19084559#19084559 which also uses my method

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done:

```
public class SMSSender extends IntentService {

public static final String INTENT_MESSAGE_SENT = "message.sent";
public static final String INTENT_MESSAGE_DELIVERED = "message.delivered";

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra.message";
public static final String EXTRA_RECEIVERS = "extra.receivers";

public SMSSender() {
    super("SMSSender");
}

private final String TAG = "SendSMS";


private static class IDGenerator {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static int nextValue() {
        return counter.getAndIncrement();
    }
}

private void sendSMS(String message, String[] receivers) {

    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();

    ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(message);

    PendingIntent sentPI = null;
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = null;

    Intent sentIntent = new Intent(INTENT_MESSAGE_SENT);

    int sentID = IDGenerator.nextValue();
    sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SMSSender.this, sentID, sentIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(INTENT_MESSAGE_DELIVERED);

    int deliveredID = IDGenerator.nextValue();
    deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SMSSender.this, deliveredID,
            deliveryIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Log.i(TAG, "sending SMS: parts: " + parts.size() + " message: "
            + message);

    if (parts.size() > 1) {
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = null;
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredIntents = null;

        sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        deliveredIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            sentIntents.add(sentPI);
            deliveredIntents.add(deliveredPI);
        }

        for (String receiver : receivers) {
            try {
                sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(receiver, null, parts,
                        sentIntents, deliveredIntents);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "illegal receiver: " + receiver);
            }

        }
    } else {
        for (String receiver : receivers) {
            try {
                sm.sendTextMessage(receiver, null, parts.get(0), sentPI,
                        deliveredPI);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "illegal receiver: " + receiver);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String[] receivers = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVERS);

    sendSMS(message, receivers);

}
```

And to use it:

```
    private void startMessageServiceIntent(String message, String receiver) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SMSSender.class);
        i.putExtra(SMSSender.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        i.putExtra(SMSSender.EXTRA_RECEIVERS, new String[] { receiver });
        startService(i)
    }
```

Notice it supports multiple receivers, which this method does not demonstrate/use.

Remember in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<service android:name="your.package.SMSSender" android:enabled="true" />
```

Optionally you can listen for when messages are sent and/or delivered:

```
    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(messageSent, new IntentFilter(SMSSender.INTENT_MESSAGE_SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(messageDelivered, new IntentFilter(
            SMSSender.INTENT_MESSAGE_DELIVERED));
```