# Message not sent completely. Some text are missing

Tags: android, sms, message

I'm trying to send a text message from my `Android` application. Everything works fine, but some of the text are missing. Here is my code:

```
String phoneNumber = "99********";  //Masked the number intentionally.
String message = "";
message += "This is Prabha, and thanks for using my application. ";
message += "Hope you enjoy this application. ";
message += "If you face any problem or issue, you can report the issue to our ";
message += "official mail id: pbha701@yahoo.com.";

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

I am receiving the message, but it is not full. Some text are missing. I'm getting only the below text:

**`This is Prabha, and thanks for using my application. Hope you enjoy this application. If you face any problem or issue, you can report the issue to our officia`**

I've added the below permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

I am not able to find why the remaining text are truncated. Should I add any other permission or any setting changes required? Any ideas or help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the code from my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083158/send-sms-until-it-is-successful/19084559#19084559 please upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method available in `SmsManager` class.

`sendTextMessage()` method available in `SmsManager` class can send a text message of length 160 characters only.

To send multi-part SMS, divide the message using `divideMessage()` method available in SmsManager class. Then send this `parts` as an parameter in `sendMultipartTextMessage()`, as shown below:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message); 
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```