# Incoming messages automatically read?

Tags: android

**I am using broadcast receiver class to read the messages automatically**

> But Iam facing some problems,

- 1. I am using indent to pass the data to another activity, I do not know is this the proper approach? If any better way please let me know.
- 2. My app automatically read the OTP from the message that was okay, but it reads every message whenever a new message arives (like customer care message and any) I want read the message only the app in running state.

> Here my code,

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
String message;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Intent a = new Intent(context, OtpConformation.class);
                a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                a.putExtra("KEY_1", message);
                context.startActivity(a);

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

}`

> In Another activity `

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    message = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_1");
    OtpEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Otp_editText);
    OtpEdt.setText(message);`
```

> In My manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: you can check if application Is In ForegroundMode. refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11030799/4148757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Indent is the good way to data communication over activities

  > [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)
- receive sms even if app is closed

  > [android: receive sms even if app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813707/android-receive-sms-even-if-app-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

Question:1 
I am using intent to pass the data to another activity,but don't need intent, any other ideas for pass the data to another activity?

> Ans: You may want to consider the SharedPreference objects. It has a
>   simple API and is accessible across an application's activities. Here
>   is an example -
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
>
> refer official documentation here -
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Question 2:My app automatically read the message while app was closed time? i want read the message only app is running time

> Answer : You can check app state by  `ActivityManager`. Please refer
>   following method.

```
public static boolean isAppRunning(Context context)
    {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();


        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningAppProcessInfos) {

            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList)
                {
                    Log.i("GCM", activeProcess + ":" + processInfo.importance);

                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```