# Application force close while sending sms

Tags: android, sms, forceclose, smsmanager

I am developing an application which will send sms directly from my application, here is the code iam using to send and sms, if i replace finalmessage with some character like "hello" it work fine.. but if i use finalmessage it will simply force close.. and one more thing finalmessage contains around 500 character. So i still dont understand what is the problem and why it getting force close.

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
PendingIntent delivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
sm.sendTextMessage(stringnumber, null,finalmessage, sent, delivered);
```

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083158/send-sms-until-it-is-successful/19084559#19084559. please upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because

`sm.sendTextMessage(stringnumber, null,finalmessage, sent, delivered);`

it will send only the sms characters less than 160 only if you want to send sms with more than 160 characters then you need to use the method

```
sendMultipartTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, ArrayList<String> parts, ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents, ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents)
```

check here for more details..[SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)