# SMS sending to multiple numbers not being sent

Tags: android, sms

I am sending an SMS to multiple numbers. When I choose only one, it works, and the message is being sent immediately. But when I use multiple (3 for example) SMS Intent is opened, but after I click Send button I see `"Sending..."` message all the time, SMS is not sent.

```
Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sms.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
sms.putExtra("address", getSMSNumbers);
sms.putExtra("sms_body", "Help!!!");
startActivity(sms);
```

And `getSMSNumbers` String looks like this: `512991220;505202222;606123456`.
What is wrong? Why isn't the message being sent and it's "sending" all the time?

Also I see when I have more than 1 number, `it's being converted` to MMS - why?

Comment: If you do not mind sending directly from your app, you can use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083158/send-sms-until-it-is-successful/19084559#19084559

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this - needed to turn off "Group Messaging" in AVD Settings. App was trying to send MMS and that's why it wasn't being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could loop through the numbers and send messages one by one, like this

```
android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault().
sendTextMessage("00112233", null, "Message body text", null, null);
```